# C# Project(build in Msbuild v12) code analysis in sonarqube 5.6.5 using sonar scanner msbuild v2.2

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Presently am using the sonarqube v4.5.6 & sonar runner 2.4 to do the analysis for the dotnet code built on the Msbuild v12(VS2013) but now am trying to upgrade sonar (to sonarqube v5.6.5 & sonar scanner for MsBuild v2.2) but am getting failure while i build the project using MsBuild v12(after begin & before end of the Scanner). please suggest me to use the upgraded sonar to work with the MsBuild v12...

Please feel free to contact me, if you need further details from me...

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [compatibility docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Compatibility) SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild doesn't work with MSBuild 12. You'll need to compile with MSBuild 14, possibly using the `TargetFrameworkVersion` property.

Comment: @Ann Thanks for your valuable response. Here my question is If my project doesn't support the higher(.Net framework 4.5+) versions(Current its works & build on .Net framework 4  bcoz lots of its library files supports only framework 4 if we upgrade to .Net framework 4.5+  then it requires lots of effort.) So Please suggest me some tweaks or workaround to use sonarqube v5.6.5 for c# code analysis (using sonarqube.scanner.msbuild or some other plugins).

Comment: @user7014262: Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended Support End Date: [1/12/2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=Microsoft%20.NET%20Framework%204)